# Spring Data: MongoDB criteria using $toDouble

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongodb, spring-mongo

I have this console query:

```
db.testcol.find({ $expr: { $lte: [ { $toDouble: "$someField" }, 5 ] } })
```

I want to write it programmatically using Criteria so I can do the following:

```
mongoTemplate.find(new Query(criteria), MyClass.class)
```

I tried:

```
Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("someField").lte(5)
```

But I don't really know where I can put the `$toDouble` part.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [Criteria.expr()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Criteria.html#expr(org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoExpression)) method:

```
MongoExpression expr = ComparisonOperators.Lte
              .valueOf(ConvertOperators.ToDouble.toDouble("$someField"))
              .lessThanEqualToValue(5);     
Criteria criteria = Criteria.expr(expr);
mongoTemplate.find(Query.query(criteria), MyClass.class);
```

**Alternative solution:** Not all MongoDB queries are easily done in the "Spring way". You may run the [query operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/) JSON this way:

```
collection.find(query) == collection.aggregate([{"$match": query}])
```

---

```
Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(ctx -> new Document("$match", 
    Document.parse("{ $expr: { $lte: [ { $toDouble: '$someField' }, 5 ] } }")));        
mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, MyClass.class, MyClass.class).getMappedResults();
```